# Groovy Equivalent: javascript object methods

Tags: grails, groovy

In JavaScript you can do the following:

```
var obj = {
    property: 1,
    method1: function() {
      //...
    },
    method2: function() {
      //...
    }
  };

obj.method1()
```

I am wondering if there is a groovy equivalent for this (a map containing a method). I know this is just like a class, but I dont want a class ha..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can put closures inside a map.  But this is not the way to get
objects in Groovy.  There is no concept of "this", that knows about the
map.

```
def obj = [
  inc: { it + 1 }
]

println obj.inc(10)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for! I tried various forms of syntax except your answer. Also good to know about "this".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Javascript is not OOP. They have OBJECTS but that is it. What you are showing is an OBJECT.

In Groovy, you can do this with a class that can instantiate the object and then you can do that on the object. For example you can [create a CommandObject](https://github.com/orubel/Beapi-API-Framework/blob/master/src/main/groovy/net/nosegrind/apiframework/ParamsDescriptor.groovy) (which is what you are probably wanting) and then fill in the properties like you want or fill them in on instantiation. For example (using above example):

```
def paramsDesc = new ParamsDescriptor()
paramsDesc.paramType = 'paramtype'
paramsDesc.keyType = 'keyType'
paramsDesc.name = 'name'
paramsDesc.idReferences = 'id'
paramsDesc.description = 'desc'
paramsDesc.mockData = 'mock'
paramsDesc.values = []
```

OR (if you create a constructor) you can instantiate all at once:

```
def paramsDesc = new ParamsDescriptor('paramtype','keyType','name','id','desc','mock',[])
```

CommandObjects can have methods and functions (like above). But you just have to instantiate them first (def paramsDesc = new ParamsDescriptor())

This is the difference between a class and an object; think of a class as the blueprint and the object as what is created from the blueprint.